# How to use regex and limit in split function

Tags: java

I am beginner to Java, In my code I am executing a Dos Command and it gave me output. From my I want to how to split a sentence into two parts, I have attached my code and output in this post

See my code

```
import java.io.*;
import java.util.*;

public class NetStat {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try
        {
            Process p=Runtime.getRuntime().exec("netstat -an");
            BufferedReader rd=new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
            String lines=rd.readLine();
            while(lines != null)
            {
                System.out.println(lines);                      
                lines=rd.readLine();
            }
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

    }

}
```

The Output of the above code is:

```
Active Connections

  Proto  Local Address          Foreign Address        State
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1052           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1053           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7077           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.8.254:139      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.8.254:1097     192.168.10.100:1433    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.8.254:1098     192.168.10.100:1433    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.8.254:1099     192.168.10.100:1433    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.8.254:1110     192.168.10.100:1433    ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.8.254:2341     192.168.8.120:8014     ESTABLISHED
  TCP    192.168.8.254:2342     192.168.8.254:7077     TIME_WAIT
  TCP    [::]:135               [::]:0                 LISTENING       0
  TCP    [::]:1052              [::]:0                 LISTENING       0
  TCP    [::]:13600             [::]:0                 LISTENING       0
  UDP    0.0.0.0:161            *:*                    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:445            *:*                    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:500            *:*                    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:1048           *:*                    
  UDP    0.0.0.0:4500           *:*                    
  UDP    127.0.0.1:123          *:*                    
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1026         *:*                    
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1049         *:*                    
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1061         *:*                    
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1101         *:*                    
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1120         *:*                    
  UDP    127.0.0.1:1900         *:*                    
  UDP    192.168.8.254:123      *:*                    
  UDP    192.168.8.254:137      *:*                    
  UDP    192.168.8.254:138      *:*                    
  UDP    192.168.8.254:1900     *:*
```

I want to split my output into two part like below

```
Split ted part 1= [TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0]
Split ted part 2= [LISTENING]
```

please share your Ideas !...

Comment: What about `TCP    [::]:13600             [::]:0                 LISTENING       0`?. Should the last `0` be part of second array?

Comment: did you want to split only the first value?

Answer (score 0):

Something like this *might* work for you :

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String s = "TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING";
    String[] arr = s.split("\\s+(?=[A-Z]+)");
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
    System.out.println(arr.length);
    System.out.println("part1 : "+ arr[0]);
    System.out.println("part2 : "+ arr[1]);
}
```

O/P :

```
[TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0, LISTENING]
2
part1 : TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0
part2 : LISTENING
```

Answer (score 0):

You could try this also,

```
String s = "  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING\n" + 
        "  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING\n" + 
        "  TCP    0.0.0.0:1052           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING\n" + 
        "  TCP    0.0.0.0:1053           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING\n" + 
        "  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING\n" + 
        "  TCP    0.0.0.0:7077           0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING\n" + 
        "  TCP    192.168.8.254:139      0.0.0.0:0              LISTENING";
String parts[] = s.split("\n");
for (String i: parts)
{
    String[] f= i.split("\\s+(?=\\S+$)");
    String part1 = f[0];
    String part2 = f[1];
    System.out.println(part1);
    System.out.println(part2);
}
```

Output:

```
  TCP    0.0.0.0:135            0.0.0.0:0
LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:445            0.0.0.0:0
LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1052           0.0.0.0:0
LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:1053           0.0.0.0:0
LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:3389           0.0.0.0:0
LISTENING
  TCP    0.0.0.0:7077           0.0.0.0:0
LISTENING
  TCP    192.168.8.254:139      0.0.0.0:0
LISTENING
```